# best way to dynamically update a details page in Jquery Mobile SPA with knockout

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

Im using Jquery Mobile to build a Single Page Application (SPA), Im using Knockout.js for the model and data binding. In the application I have a listview to show a menu of food items. When the user makes a selection from the list view I want to bring up a food details page with details about that item. I have already loaded into knockout.js observable Array the menu items and most of their details.. (think simple food truck menu).  But Im uncertain on how to dynamically load the details page as a Single PAge Application...

Should i make another ajax call to the server to dynamically update the details page.

```
<a href="myFoodDetailsPage.php?id=3" rel="external">Details</a>
```

Or is there some clever way to just dynamically update the details page with the detail using the listView item  id I selected. In other words is there a way to use knockout.js to dynamically build the details page(s) based on selected listview items?

Being new to SPA development, I'm wondering how much of this application can be dynamically generated inside a single page..

**Jquery Mobile Menu listview (excerpt)**

```
    <ul data-bind="foreach: FoodsModelArray"  data-role="listview"  >
    <li >
       <a href="#uib_page_food_details" data-transition="slide">
        <p><strong> <span data-bind="text: food_name"> </span> </p>
        <span data-bind="text: food_desc_abbreviated"> </span> </p>
        <p>Price: <span data-bind="text: food_price">  </span></p>
         </a>   
        </li>
        </ul> <!-- end of list view -->
```

**Jquery Mobile Details Page**

```
    <!--  start of Food DETAILS page -->          
      <div class="upage" id="uib_page_food_details" data-role="page">

      <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-id="main-header">
        //header code would go here
        </div>

    <div data-role="content">
          <form action="#uib_page_food_details" method="get" >

     <div data-role="fieldcontain">
         <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">     
          Chicken Gyro
     Cost: 12.99
    5oz of grilled chicken cutlet on Pita Bread with Tzaiki sauce
    500 calories.
         </fieldset>
        </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="title">Notes:</label>
                <textarea name="notes" id="notes">  </textarea>
            </div>

            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
     <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
    <legend>Rating:</legend>
    <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Food Rating:</label>
<select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0">
  <option value="EXCELLENT">EXCELLENT</option>
  <option value="GOOD">GOOD</option>
  <option value="OK">OK</option>
  <option value="POOR">POOR</option>
  <option value="TERRIBLE">TERRIBLE</option>
 </select>
  </fieldset>
 </div>
            <a href="#uib_page_nebu" data-role="button"   data-theme="b" id="btn_update_plate" data-transition="slide" >Update</a>

        </form>
    </div>  

      </div>
<!-- End of FOOD DETAILS page -->
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be constructed into a single page. how you do that will depend on how large the application will be as you will need to manage page lifecycles etc.

This is a very basic idea of managing a master-detail view:

```js
var data = [{
    id: 1,
    foodName: 'Pie',
    foodDesc: 'Meat Pie',
    foodPrice: '$4.00'
}, {
    id: 2,
    foodName: 'Chicken Gyro',
    foodDesc: '5oz of grilled chicken cutlet on Pita Bread with Tzaiki sauce 500 calories.',
    foodPrice: '$12.99'
}, {
    id: 3,
    foodName: 'Lamb Roast',
    foodDesc: 'Roast Lamb with gravy',
    foodPrice: '$10.00'
}, {
    id: 4,
    foodName: 'Apple Pie',
    foodDesc: 'Apple Pie with ice cream',
    foodPrice: '$6.50'
}];

var FoodModel = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    self.id = data.id || 0;
    self.food_name = ko.observable(data.foodName || '');
    self.food_desc_abbreviated = ko.observable(data.foodDesc || '');
    self.food_price = ko.observable(data.foodPrice || '$0.00');
    return self;
}
var Vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedItem = ko.observable(null);
    self.foodsModelArray = ko.observableArray($.map(data, function (item){return new FoodModel(item);}));

    self.selectItem = function (item) {
        alert('load data here for item ' + item.food_name() );
        self.selectedItem(item);
    }
    self.clearSelection = function(){
        self.selectedItem(null);
    }
    self.detailVisible = ko.pureComputed(function(){
        return self.selectedItem() !== null;
    });
    self.listVisible = ko.pureComputed(function (){
        return self.selectedItem() === null;
    });
    return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(new Vm());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<ul data-bind="foreach: foodsModelArray, visible: listVisible" data-role="listview">
    <li> <a data-transition="slide" data-bind='click: $parent.selectItem'>
        <p><strong> <span data-bind="text: food_name"> </span> </p>
        <span data-bind="text: food_desc_abbreviated"> </span> </p>
        <p>Price: <span data-bind="text: food_price">  </span></p>
         </a> 
    </li>
</ul>
<!-- end of list view -->
<!-- start of Food DETAILS page -->
<div class="upage" id="uib_page_food_details" data-role="page" data-bind="with: selectedItem, visible: detailVisible">
    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header" data-id="main-header" data-bind="text: food_name">//header code would go here</div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <form action="#uib_page_food_details" method="get">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal"><span data-bind='text: food_desc_abbreviated'></span>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <label for="title">Notes:</label>
                <textarea name="notes" id="notes"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
                    <legend>Rating:</legend>
                    <label for="select-choice-0" class="select">Food Rating:</label>
                    <select name="select-choice-0" id="select-choice-0">
                        <option value="EXCELLENT">EXCELLENT</option>
                        <option value="GOOD">GOOD</option>
                        <option value="OK">OK</option>
                        <option value="POOR">POOR</option>
                        <option value="TERRIBLE">TERRIBLE</option>
                    </select>
                </fieldset>
            </div> 
            <a data-role="button" data-theme="b" data-transition="slide" data-bind="click: $parent.clearSelection">Back</a>
            <a href="#uib_page_nebu" data-role="button" data-theme="b" id="btn_update_plate" data-transition="slide">Update</a>
```